# Accessing SQL DB in Play Framework using Anorm

Tags: scala, playframework, anorm

I am new to Play Framework and created the DB connection in Play Framework and made some mistakes. I created the database in my models and its shows some error while compiling I ain't know what I have done wrong.

```scala
package models

import anorm._
import play.api.db._
import play.api.Play.current
import play.api.db.DB

case class Contact(id: Long, name: String, emailAddress: String)

object Contact {
  def all = {
    DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
      SQL("SELECT * FROM  Contacts").map { row =>
        Contact(
          id = row[Long]("id"),
          name = row[String]("name"),
          emailAddress = row[String]("emailAddress")
        )
      }
    }
  }.toList
}
```

---

```
@(Contacts: List[models.Contact])
<html>
   <head>
      <title>CONTACT</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      @Contacts.map{contact=>
      @contact.name
      @contact.emailAddress
      }
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to add the erorst details if you want help about

Comment: it would be very helpful if you include these compile errors also

Comment: It looks like you are using an old version of Play and Slick, you may want to follow a more up to date example.

Comment: Anorm, not slick, still indicating version is useful to get help